# Use Index.php to route navigation with Smarty

Tags: php, smarty

Newbie to Smarty here and I have, what may seem like, a dumb question.

I would like to be able to route the user's navigation through my index.php file however, I am unsure as to whether I am making a dumb php error or a dumb smarty error. I was hoping someone could help me. To be completely honest I do not even know if something like this is even possible with Smarty.

For a general overview of code:

```
    1) If a user is logged in a SESSION variable is set
    2) If user is logged in and the user has clicked a link route them to apporpriate page with smart->display("whateverPage.tpl");
```

Here is some code which will focus primarily on routing the user to the "favorites.tpl" page (from index.php/index.tpl) if they click the "Favorites" link in the navigation. I am attempting to use my Index for routing as a means of codensing my entire project.

Please be easy on me :) Thanks!

```
<?php
require('init.php');
require('smarty_header.php');

session_start();


if(empty($_SESSION['user_id']) && empty($_SESSION['first_name'])) // If there is a session set
{
    if(isset($_POST['clicked'])) //If the session is set and the user has clicked a navigation link switch on which link was clicked
    {
        $navigation_linked_clicked = $_POST['clicked'];

        switch ($naviagtion_linked_clicked)
        {
            case "f":
                ShowFavorites($smarty, $link_array);
                break;
            case "t":
                ShowTasks($smarty, $link_array);
                break;
            case "a":
                ShowAdministration($smarty, $link_array);
                break;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        ShowLogIn($smarty); //If the session is set but the user has not clicked a link - ie the user just logged in
    }
}
else //There is not a session - ie this is the user's first visit to our page or the user has logged out.
{
    ShowLoggedInUser($smarty, $link_array);
}
```

Here are the functions I am calling

```
function ShowFavorites($smarty, $link_array)
{
    $welcome_msg = "Your Favorites";
    $user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
    $user_name = $_SESSION['first_name'];
    $privilege = $_SESSION['privilege'];
    $logged_in = true;
    $user = new User();
    $favorites_array = $user->GetFavorites($mysqli, $user_id);
    $smarty->assign('user_name', $user_name);
    $smarty->assign('welcome_msg', $welcome_msg);
    $smarty->assign('logged_in', $logged_in); //logged_in sets our SMARTY logic for display purposes
    $smarty->assign('link_array', $link_array); //Link array holds values for the predetermined links the Admin/Owner sets
    $smarty->assign('favorites_array', $favorites_array);
    switch ($privilege)
    {
        case 0: //Normal User
            break;
        case 1: //Owner
            $admin = true;
            $smarty->assign('admin', $admin);
            break;
        case 2: //Admin - Not Current Used
            $admin = true;
            $smarty->assign('admin', $admin);
    }
    $smarty->display('favorites.tpl');  
}

function ShowLogIn($smarty)
{
    $welcome_msg = "Please Log In To Continue";
    $logged_in = false;
    $smarty->assign('welcome_msg', $welcome_msg);
    $smarty->assign('logged_in', $logged_in); //logged_in sets our SMARTY logic for display purposes
    $smarty->display('index.tpl');
}
```

If you have any critism or tips/tricks that I could use to accomplish my general goal I am all ears!

Lastly, just in case you were curious as to what I am doing to send the $_POST['clicked'] (Which may be where the problem is):

```
$('#favorites_link').on('click', function(event)
{
    $.ajax({
        url: "index.php",
        data: {clicked: "f"},
        type: "POST",
        success: function(data)
        {

        },
        error: function(data)
        {

        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems as though I may have answered my own question. If anyone in the future has this issue, this is how I solved it. (NOTE: Changed some methods around from the original post but same logic remains)

```
require('init.php');
require('smarty_header.php');
require('php/UserClass.php');

session_start();

if(CheckSession()) // If there is a session set
{
    if(isset($_POST['clicked'])) //If the session is set and the user has clicked a navigation link switch on which link was clicked
    {

        $navigation_linked_clicked = $_POST['clicked'];


        switch ($navigation_linked_clicked)
        {
            case "f":
                ShowFavorites($smarty, $link_array, $mysqli);
                break;
            case "t":
                ShowTasks($smarty, $link_array);
                break;
            case "a":
                ShowAdministration($smarty, $link_array);
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }   
    }
    else
    {
        ShowLoggedInUser($smarty, $link_array);
    }

}
else //There is not a session - ie this is the user's first visit to our page or the user has logged out.
{
    ShowLogIn($smarty);
}
```

And the following function changed. Seems as though fetch() is what I was looking for. Echo the data back to the AJAX call

```
function ShowFavorites($smarty, $link_array, $mysqli)
{
    $welcome_msg = "Your Favorites";
    $user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
    $logged_in = true;
    $user = new User();
    $favorites_array = $user->GetFavorites($mysqli, $user_id);
    $smarty->assign('user_name', SetSmartyUserFirstName());
    $smarty->assign('welcome_msg', $welcome_msg);
    $smarty->assign('logged_in', $logged_in); //logged_in sets our SMARTY logic for display purposes
    $smarty->assign('link_array', $link_array); //Link array holds values for the predetermined links the Admin/Owner sets
    $smarty->assign('favorites_array', $favorites_array);
    $smarty->assign('admin', SetSmartyUserPrivilege($_SESSION['privilege']));
    $page = $smarty->fetch('favorites.tpl');
    echo($page);

}
```

AJAX - Append the echo to body tag

```
$('#favorites_link').on('click', function(event)
{
    event.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url: "index.php",
        data: {clicked: "f"},
        type: "POST",
        success: function(data)
        {
            $("body").html(data);
        },
        error: function(data)
        {

        }
    });
});
```